# How to pull and push the changes from one local repository to another local repository using TortoiseGit

Tags: git, tortoisegit

How to pull and push the changes from one local repository to another local repository using TortoiseGit

eg: For suppose developer1 has his own local repository in his machine and developer-2 has his own local repository in his machine.

How could developer-2 pull/push his changes to developer-1 local repository using TortoiseGit?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the remotes that you need and then pull/push from this repo.

#### For example:

```
git remote add remote <url>
git remote add remote2 <url>

git checkout master // assume remote1
git pull remote2 master

git push remote1/remote2 master
```

Now you can pull push between those 2 repos.

Comment: remote add remote <URL> .......is working with main GIT repository, but not with local repository..................what will be the URL for the repository which is in the local machine

Comment: Itss working on the local repository as well. the url is the ip of the other developer

Comment: is there a structured way to give the IP along with the path of local repository?

Comment: You can clone with ip or add remote with IP